# Undefined variable $configuration while installing Laravel reCaptcha

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I am using [this](https://github.com/biscolab/laravel-recaptcha) package for Laravel ReCaptcha setup and following the documentation for configuration. I am getting the following error on the blade file when I put `{!! htmlScriptTagJsApi($configuration) !!}` under the `<head>` section of the layout file. I am using Laravel 5.6 and Recaptcha v2 and Laravel Package's v4.

```
Undefined variable: configuration (View: /proj/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is somewhat vague. It sounds like that `$configuration` array only takes a key to set the language. Try leaving it blank `{!! htmlScriptTagJsApi([]) !!}` or setting a language explicitly `{!! htmlScriptTagJsApi(['lang' => 'en']) !!}`.